# Could not load data from data source

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I used ArcCatalog 10.2.2 to connect to enterprise database (SQL SERVER 2012) I've created before.

Some feature classes load just fine. But others show this error when I try to view data table[image]

This feature class works fine in personal DB, this error only happened in Enterprise DB.

Thing I've tried:

1. Re-install SQL Native Client 12
2. Export error feature class and re-import to DB

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please always include error messages as text rather than pictures so that they can be available for future searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,I've found out what really cause to this error.

- My region setting define that "," is decimal symbol and "." is digit symbol
- When i tried to connect to SQL Database ArcGIS has problem reading double field from my feature class

I've changed my region setting and now it works perfectly.